# React url changes but render is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-saga

i want to redirect to a page after an api, when i dispatch the url changes but the view is not rendering, It works when i refresh the page. How can i redirect from redux-saga.

**saga.js**

```
export function* PQuotation({ payload }) {
 try {
const params = { PurchaseQuotation: payload.toJS() };

const res = yield call(request, `${BASE_URL}/purchase/quotations`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    ...authHeader(),
    module: `${modules.PurchaseQuotation}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(params),
});

  yield put(purchaseQuotationCreateSuccess(res));
  yield put(push(`/some/page`));    //redirect to another page
} catch (err) {
  yield put(purchaseQuotationCreateError(err));
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
render() {
return (
  <Fragment>
    <Helmet titleTemplate="%s ERP" defaultTitle="ERP">
      <meta name="description" content="ERP Application" />
    </Helmet>
     <BrowserRouter> 
    <Switch>
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path="/login"
        render={props => (
          <AuthLayout>
            <Login {...props} />
          </AuthLayout>
        )}
      />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} /> 
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/some/page" component={SomePage} />          
   </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Fragment>
  );
  }
```

Comment: From where the push is imported?

Comment: Check out [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router).

Comment: i imported push from 'connected-react-router'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to follow separation of concepts principle where React components are responsible for rendering, and Redux-Saga is responsible for side effects.

So the approach should be:

1. In saga do `yield put(purchaseQuotationCreateSuccess(res));`. I suspect that this action will update state. Set some variable indicating, that purchase quotation has been successfully created. Say `isPurchaseQuoCreated: true`
2. Upgrade/wrap route `<PrivateRoute />` so it will be connected to store and in case of purchase quotation has been successfully created it will redirect.

(Code below is not tested. Use it as hint)

```
const PurchaseQuotationRoute = ({isPurchaseQuoCreated, ...rest}) => (
    isPurchaseQuoCreated ? 
        <Redirect to='/some/page'/>
    :
        <PrivateRoute {...rest} />
)

export default connect(state => ({ isPurchaseQuoCreated: state.isPurchaseQuoCreated }))(PurchaseQuotationRoute)
```

And use in `App.js`

```
    <Switch>
      <PurchaseQuotationRoute
        exact
        path="/login"
        render={props => (
          <AuthLayout>
            <Login {...props} />
          </AuthLayout>
        )}
      />
      <PurchaseQuotationRoute exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
      <PurchaseQuotationRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} /> 
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/some/page" component={SomePage} />          
   </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Take a note that for `/some/page` `<PrivateRoute/>` left in place. We don't want to redirect if we already on `/some/page`.